# About ConcurrentHashMap get() method

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

In JDK6 get() method

```
V get(Object key, int hash) { 
  if (count != 0) { // read-volatile 
    HashEntry<K,V> e = getFirst(hash); 
    while (e != null) { 
      if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) { 
        V v = e.value; 
        if (v != null) 
          return v; 
        return readValueUnderLock(e); // recheck 
      } 
      e = e.next; 
    } 
  } 
  return null; 
}
```

In JDK6 it will check 'value!=null' but in JDK7 not，why？

Comment: Please make sure code is formatted correctly, and also add the equivalent code for JDK7. A question like this will likely attract a lot of guess work, because only persons intimately familiar with the inner workings of this code will know for sure.

Comment: If I had to guess to, it is likely to do with the visibility guarantees provided by `readValueUnderLock`.